# How to delete a file using Windows Sidebar Gadget API?

Tags: javascript, windows-desktop-gadgets

I know that Windows Sidebar Gadget API provides functionality beyond normal Javascript capabilities. Does it manipulate files? How?

I didn't find how to do it in the [API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965853(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [System.Shell.RecycleBin.deleteItem](http://retVal%20=%20System.Shell.RecycleBin.deleteItem%28%20%20%20strItemToDelete%20%29) method.

```
retVal = System.Shell.RecycleBin.deleteItem(
  strItemToDelete
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a method of deleting files using the Gadget API, but you can use [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(v=VS.85).aspx)'s [DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thx0f315(v=VS.85).aspx) method:

```
var oFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
oFSO.DeleteFile(System.Gadget.path+"\\myfile.txt");
```